# OdataReader has OdataEntry with empty Odataproperties C# / OdataLib

Tags: c#, odata

I am using odata library to read OData feed but Entry doenst show me any properties.

```
using (ODataMessageReader messageReader = new ODataMessageReader(message.GetResponse(), new ODataMessageReaderSettings()))
{
    ODataReader reader = messageReader.CreateODataFeedReader();
    while (reader.Read())
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.State)
            {
                case ODataReaderState.EntryStart:
                {
                    ODataEntry entry = (ODataEntry)reader.Item;
                    var atomMetadata = entry.Properties.ToList(); 
                    break;
                }
             }
         }
}
```

here `var atomMetadata = entry.Properties.ToList();` no properties are returned.

Comment: Please show your work. Give more information to us. People can't read your mind.

Comment: People are too quick for comments...I am hoping I will get answer also that fast...

Comment: I m updating code also in the post...gimme sometime

Comment: @SonerGönül: code updated as per ur suggestion

Comment: What does the payload on the wire look like? Does it actually have any properties?

Comment: yes response payload have properties and related data. I have also tried to read string content using same response object and I am getting complete data properly. Is there any settings or anything which needs to be take care ?while reading response using odatalib ?

Comment: "ODataReaderState.EntryEnd" will return properties and I am searching in "ODataReaderState.EntryStart"...my problem get resolved.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't catch that :). Could you post your solution as an answer (and mark it correct) so others searching for the same problem can find the solution?

Comment: I updated solution as u have suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"ODataReaderState.**EntryEnd**" will return properties and not "ODataReaderState.**EntryStart**"

```
using (ODataMessageReader messageReader = new ODataMessageReader(message.GetResponse(), new ODataMessageReaderSettings()))
{
    ODataReader reader = messageReader.CreateODataFeedReader();
    while (reader.Read())
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.State)
            {
                case ODataReaderState.EntryEnd:
                {
                    ODataEntry entry = (ODataEntry)reader.Item;
                    var atomMetadata = entry.Properties.ToList(); 
                    break;
                }
             }
         }
}
```